# Trying to work this code in JS.

Tags: javascript, html

The objective is to make a webpage that counts the time a user has been on that webpage. My approach has been to use a stopwatch to display the time user has been on the page. I have also used a window.onblur() function to see if the user is on the same webpage or not. These two codes run perfectly fine on their own. I'm just unable to make them into one program.

```
Stopwatch program: 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<h1 font size= 55 align= "center"><time>00:00:00</time></h1>
<h2 id= "mee" align= "center"></h2>
<h3  id="she" align= "center"></h3>
<button id="start" class= "fof"align= "center">start</button>
<button id="stop" align= "center">stop</button>
<button id="clear" align= "center">clear</button>
<style>
.fof{ height: 50px;
border-radius: 50px;
}
</style>
<script>
var h1 = document.getElementsByTagName('h1')[0],
start = document.getElementById('start'),
stop = document.getElementById('stop'),
clear = document.getElementById('clear'),
seconds = 0, minutes = 0, hours = 0,
t;




function add() {
    seconds++;
    if (seconds >= 60) {
        seconds = 0;
        minutes++;
        if (minutes >= 60) {
            minutes = 0;
            hours++;
    }
}

    h1.textContent = (hours ? (hours > 9 ? hours : "0" + hours) : "00")         
+ ":" + (minutes ? (minutes > 9 ? minutes : "0" + minutes) : "00")
 + ":" +   (seconds > 9 ? seconds : "0" + seconds);

timer();

}


function timer() {
t = setTimeout(add, 1000);
}
timer();


/* Start button */
start.onclick = timer;



/* Stop button */
stop.onclick = function() {
clearTimeout(t);
    document.getElementById("mee").innerHTML= minutes;
    document.getElementById("she").innerHTML= seconds;

}

/* Clear button */
clear.onclick = function() {
h1.textContent = "00:00:00";
seconds = 0; minutes = 0; hours = 0;
}




</script>
</body>
</html>

Program to see if user is on same webpage:
    var quitter = false;
window.onblur = function () {

  if(!quitter){
        quitter = true;
        alert('You left');

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check below fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/yogesh078/5vfxk9e1/1/

Javascript Code:

```
var h1 = document.getElementsByTagName('h1')[0],
    start = document.getElementById('start'),
    stop = document.getElementById('stop'),
    clear = document.getElementById('clear'),
    seconds = 0,
    minutes = 0,
    hours = 0,
    t;
var timerRunning = false;



function add() {
    seconds++;
    if (seconds >= 60) {
        seconds = 0;
        minutes++;
        if (minutes >= 60) {
            minutes = 0;
            hours++;
        }
    }

    h1.textContent = (hours ? (hours > 9 ? hours : "0" + hours) : "00") +
        ":" + (minutes ? (minutes > 9 ? minutes : "0" + minutes) : "00") +
        ":" + (seconds > 9 ? seconds : "0" + seconds);

    timer();

}


function timer() {
    if (timerRunning) {
        clearTimeout(t);
    }
    t = setTimeout(add, 1000);
    timerRunning = true;
}
timer();


/* Start button */
start.onclick = timer;



/* Stop button */
stop.onclick = function() {
    clearTimeout(t);
    timerRunning = false;
    document.getElementById("mee").innerHTML = minutes;
    document.getElementById("she").innerHTML = seconds;

}

/* Clear button */
clear.onclick = function() {
    h1.textContent = "00:00:00";
    seconds = 0;
    minutes = 0;
    hours = 0;
}




var quitter = false;
window.onblur = function() {
    clearTimeout(t);
    timerRunning = false;
    quitter = true;
    alert('You left');
}

window.onmousemove = function() {
    if (!timerRunning) {
        timer();
    }
};
```